# How to implement Vuetify date picker

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to use Date Picker from Vuetify. I got an error after adding the template taken from vuetify.

Error : [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "disabled". Expected Boolean, got String with value "true".

Code :

```
           <v-col cols="12" md="3">
                 <v-menu
                  v-model="menu2"
                  :close-on-content-click="false"
                  :nudge-right="40"
                  transition="scale-transition"
                  offset-y
                  min-width="auto"
                  
                >
                  <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                    <v-text-field
                     
                      v-model="date"
                      label="Picker without buttons"
                      prepend-icon="mdi-calendar"
                      readonly
                      v-bind="attrs"
                      v-on="on"
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </template>
                  <v-date-picker
                    v-model="date"
                    @input="menu2 = false"
                  ></v-date-picker>
                </v-menu>
              </v-col>  




 date: (new Date(Date.now() - (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toISOString().substr(0, 10),        
    menu2: false,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the error, it tells you exactly what is wrong. `disabled` is expecting a boolean value. You passed it a string, in order to make it boolean you need to bind it. The code that you provided is not what is causing the error.

Check elsewhere in your code for

```
disabled="true"
```

and change it to

```
:disabled="true"
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem was not related with the date picker as you said.

Comment: Glad to help :)